# unable to connect hdfs with URI

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am unable to connect hdfs using URI here is my sample code

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://localhost:9000/vedio/realvedio.mp4"),configuration);
    InputStream inputStream = hdfs.open(new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/vedio/realvedio.mp4"));

    byte[] b = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

working fine with above code but where as i can not connect with I/P instead of local host

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://192.168.0.158:9000/vedio/realvedio.mp4"),configuration);
        InputStream inputStream = hdfs.open(new Path("hdfs://192.168.0.158:9000/vedio/realvedio.mp4"));
byte[] b = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

i am getting the following execption

```
ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: sushmag.iton.local/192.168.0.158:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45
```

guys please help me how to slove this.

Comment: Maybe set `fs.default.name` to something other than `localhost`, like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855808/hadoop-job-tracker-only-accessible-from-localhost)

Comment: Can you to execute the command hadoop fs -ls hdfs://hdfs://192.168.0.158:9000/        ?

Comment: no sachinjose i cant execute even your command also

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to execute any of the following commands successfully, which means your hdfs might be down.

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/
```

or

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://192.168.0.158:9000/
```

Start HDFS using `start-dfs.sh` script and Make sure that the following daemons are running, jps command can be used

Namenode 
Datanode